# Command-line argument issue

Tags: command-line

I have a bash script called test.sh and it current is:

```
url=
lynx -dump $url > story.txt
echo "step one completed"
```

Except when I run `./test.sh http://www.fox.com` or any website, story.txt says:

```
                            Forbidden
   You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

How do I fix it so that when I open story.txt, it displays the actual dump of the url?

Comment: this would probably be better asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: This won't work because $url has no value. Try setting it and seeing what you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script does not work for me, but I guess it does for you so we might have a different setup. I changed the script to

```
lynx -dump $1 > story.txt
echo "step one completed"
```

I run it with

```
 ./test.sh http://www.techland.ro
```

and I get the same result.

Instead of running the script with fox.com try with techland.ro and you will see that the script actually works just fine. The problem is not with your script but with the website you are trying to access. I believe it blocks website crawlers, because lynx is a command line browser it actually acts exactly like a crawler, resulting in the message you get.

You can set different rules for websites, if a website blocks unknown crawlers then it will also probably block lynx (or any other command line browser). Your script is fine, the website is blocking you.

Comment: This worked!!!! Thank you so much! My script wasn't working which is why I asked in the first place!

Answer (score 4):

That URL gives an error with `curl` too:

```
curl -i http://www.fox.com/
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 260
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Date: Thu, 06 Dec 2012 20:17:17 GMT
Connection: close

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;fox&#46;com&#47;" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;2fa2f5cc&#46;1354825037&#46;8323a81
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Apparently the site is doing some weird user agent sniffing. Passing a Firefox user agent seems to work:

```
curl -i -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/17.0 Firefox/17.0' http://www.fox.com/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 70647
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-FarmName: www.fox.com
X-FarmAddr: 10.96.57.103
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Date: Thu, 06 Dec 2012 20:22:58 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:tp="http://player.theplatform.com/" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" >
<head>
        <title>FOX Broadcasting Company - FOX Television Shows</title>
```

Comment: It's Fox after all - they fear what they don't understand (wget in this case), so they ban it. Sorry, could not resist.

Comment: That works fine on it's own. But when I run in terminal, ./test.sh http://www.fox.com it doesn't work where test.sh is now:
url=<br>
curl -i -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/17.0 Firefox/17.0' $url > story.txt<br>
echo "step one completed"

Comment: This did not work with the test.sh but thank you nevertheless!

Comment: You have to set $url to something. Instead of `url=`, try something like `url="http://www.fox.com/"`.